# iOS StreamingKit how to record/save the audio?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, streaming, avplayer

I am using https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit

for streaming a live url. works perfectly fine. I want to add recording/save of audio feature to my app. Does anyone know if this library can do this?
**If not, are there any alternatives? NOTE that I need to record LIVE streaming audio, not local file / static url.**

The page shows that you can Intercept PCM data just before its played:

```
[audioPlayer appendFrameFilterWithName:@"MyCustomFilter" block:^(UInt32 channelsPerFrame, UInt32 bytesPerFrame, UInt32 frameCount, void* frames)
{
   ...
}];
```

However, I am not sure how to convert this into actual recording / mp3 file or even intercept the actual data from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, although StreamingKit seems a little bit secretive about the format of the samples it gives you. What's the sample rate? Floats or ints? I suppose you can guess from the sample size. This example assumes 16bit ints.

```
NSURL *dstUrl = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0] ] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.m4a"];

NSLog(@"write to %@", dstUrl);

__block AVAudioFile *audioFile = nil;

[audioPlayer appendFrameFilterWithName:@"MyCustomFilter" block:^(UInt32 channelsPerFrame, UInt32 bytesPerFrame, UInt32 frameCount, void* frames)
 {
     NSError *error;

     // what's the sample rate? StreamingKit doesn't seem to tell us
     double sampleRate = 44100;

     if (!audioFile) {
         NSDictionary *settings =
         @{
           AVFormatIDKey : @(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
           AVSampleRateKey : @(sampleRate),
           AVNumberOfChannelsKey : @(channelsPerFrame),
           };

         // need commonFormat?
         audioFile = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForWriting:dstUrl settings:settings commonFormat:AVAudioPCMFormatInt16 interleaved:YES error:&error];
         if (!audioFile) {
             // error
         }
     }

     AVAudioFormat *format = [[AVAudioFormat alloc] initWithCommonFormat:AVAudioPCMFormatInt16 sampleRate:sampleRate channels:channelsPerFrame interleaved:YES];
     AVAudioPCMBuffer *buffer = [[AVAudioPCMBuffer alloc] initWithPCMFormat:format frameCapacity:frameCount];

     buffer.frameLength = frameCount;
     memmove(buffer.int16ChannelData[0], frames, frameCount*bytesPerFrame);

     if (![audioFile writeFromBuffer:buffer error:&error]) {
         NSLog(@"write error: %@", error);
     }
}];

[self.audioPlayer performSelector:@selector(removeFrameFilterWithName:) withObject:@"MyCustomFilter" afterDelay:10];
```

Comment: thank you, will try this in the morning and report back! Looking at the source code for streamingkit, i see two places where sample rate might be defined: `.mSampleRate = 44100.00,` in the `initialize` and `Float64 graphSampleRate = 44100.0;` in `createMixerUnit`

Comment: p.s. I don't think iOS exposes an mp3 encoder. You'd do better to save the mp3 packets directly, if StreamingKit lets you.

Comment: You are a GENIOUS sir!!! Thank you very much, that worked perfectly! If you have somewhere I can send a small donation for beer money, please share! saved me so much time!! Right now the m4a format is good enough, I just needed someway to record the audio, format wasn't important.

Comment: Also the 44100 sample rate works perfect. If I use anything else, it writes an error code `-66567` when doing `ExtAudioFileWrite`

Comment: Ha, I should add a donate button to my blog. P.S. what sample rates? AAC doesn't support arbitrary sample rates, but it does do most of the ones you'd think of using. You are setting it in both `AVAudioFormat` and settings dictionary, right?

Comment: I just changed the line `double sampleRate = 44100;` to `double sampleRate = 22050;` and it gave me that error. But since your current solution works perfectly, I don't worry about it. thanks again for the help, really appreciate it! :)